# Firebase initWitURL crashes [FRepo initTransactions]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, firebase

I have set up two similar firebase applications.
In both cases I call

```
self.firebase  = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kFirebaseRoot];
```

in one case everything works fine.
In the other case I get a crash

**2014-05-19 11:18:59.726 MyApp[28041:60b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FRepo initTransactions]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f50c10'**
 First throw call stack:*

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x023131e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x020928e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x023b0243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0230350b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x023030ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   MyApp                              0x0002b63b -[FRepo initWithRepoInfo:] + 187
6   MyApp                              0x0002ab05 -[FRepoManager getLocalRepo:] + 597
7   MyApp                              0x0002b3ff +[FRepoManager getRepo:] + 111
8   MyApp                              0x000544dc -[Firebase initWithUrl:] + 204
9   MyApp                              0x000172f2 -[FLPresenceManager initFirebase] + 194
```

This appears to be something going on within `Firebase`, so I presume there must be something different in the way I have set up the app in the two cases. However, I cannot see a difference.
Can anyone offer any clues?

Comment: Just so no-one wastes their time with this. I tracked it down to a problem with the other linker flags. I had added -objC instead of -ObjC

Comment: To add the linker go to Build Settings and search for Other Linkers.

Comment: This has only had 90 views in 8 months but thank you so much for posting the solution in the comments - I had the exact same problem and you just saved me hours

Answer (score 5):

This answer was posted in the comments of the question.

The problem seems to be having -objC instead of -ObjC in the linker flags.

Just for completion sake for the next person, this is exactly where it can be found: [image]